# cant use make on Mac OS Monterey

Tags: macos, cmake, darwin

I am trying to build a project using cmake. however when cmake verifies whether I have a working c compiler it fails with the output:

```
Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make -f Makefile cmTC_a842e/fast && /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_a842e.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_a842e.dir/build
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_a842e.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
    /usr/bin/clang   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -MD -MT CMakeFiles/cmTC_a842e.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/cmTC_a842e.dir/testCCompiler.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_a842e.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /Users/simon/Desktop/Sommer22/DA_Lab/cpp_impl/lab22-p4-streaming/SHJ_producer_consumer/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
    Linking C executable cmTC_a842e
    /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.24.0/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_a842e.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /usr/bin/clang  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names CMakeFiles/cmTC_a842e.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_a842e 
    ld: library not found for -lSystem
```

indeed, I do not have a libSystem.dylib installed on my Mac.

I am using clang 13 to build it.

Answer (score 0):

deleting CommandLine tools directory and doing Xcode-select --install fixed the problem